# Spring Jedis error Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, redis

I have an error with Spring Jedis using spring-date-redis and springboot.

I'm using:

- spring-data-redis version: 2.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring Jedis version: 2.9.0
- Spring-boot version: 1.5.8.RELEASE brings Spring 4.3.12.RELEASE

At Maven Respository the spring-data-redis 2.0.0.RELEASE dependencies Jedis 
 2.9.0. And Jedis 2.9.0 dependencies commons-pool2 2.4.2

So it seems no problem, at least no version mistake?

My log is:

```
Type Exception Report  

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception  

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Exception trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception  
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)  
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)  
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)  
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)  
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)  
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)  
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)  
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Root Cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private 
com.shinian.lea.service.user.UserTeamInfoService 
com.shinian.lea.controller.pve.user.UserController.userTeamInfoService; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userTeamInfoService': Injection of autowired 
dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire 
field: private org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate 
com.shinian.lea.service.user.UserTeamInfoService.redisTemplate; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'StringRedisTemplate' defined in file 
[E:\TimeYears\LEA\trunk\target\lea-0.0.1\WEB-
INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested 
exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack  
Exception Details:  
Location:  
org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.
<init>
(Lorg/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration;Lredis
/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig;)V @43: invokestatic
```

Reason:

```
Type 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPoolConfig'
```

Current Frame:

```
bci: @43  
flags: { }  
locals: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory', 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration', 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' }  
stack: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory', 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' }
```

Bytecode:

```
0x0000000: 2ab7 0004 2a03 b500 052a 04b5 0006 2abb  
0x0000010: 0007 5912 0811 18eb b700 0ab5 000b 2b12  
0x0000020: 19b8 000d 2a2b b500 1a2a 2cb8 0017 b500  
0x0000030: 0eb1                               

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)  
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)  
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)  
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)  
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)  
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)  
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)  
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)  
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)  
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)  
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)  
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)  
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help with this error?

Comment: Please copy and paste your error message (I think you can leave out the stacktrace). Also, a [mcve] could be useful.

Comment: I've submitted an edit that indents your log with four spaces to make it a preformatted code block. In the future, you can do this yourself by highlighting the code in the post editor and pressing ctrl+k

Comment: There is no such thing a Spring Jedis. From the version you've used, you won't be able to run Spring Data Redis with Spring Boot 1.x. A lot of internals changed in Spring Data, upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0 M5.